# ImageView image not being drawn when viewcontroller bgcolor is being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

running into a weird issue. Within the prepareForSegue method in my HomeViewController.m file, I'm doing this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender {

    StarViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    nextViewController.title = segue.identifier;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"redDwarfSegue"]) {

        //nextViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        nextViewController.starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];

     } else {

        nextViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        nextViewController.starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2"];

    }
}
```

In the StarViewController.h I have one property of type UIImage called starImage, which is referenced in the above code.

Finally, in my StarViewController.m file I have one property of type UIImageView called starImageView and all I am doing is this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    self.starImageView.image = self.starImage;
    self.starImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}
```

In the prepareForSegue method in my HomeViewController.m, I have deliberately commented out this line:

```
        //nextViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

What happens is that image1 loads fine when segued into the viewcontroller, but image2 does not. All I see is a the blue background color. If I were to comment out the setting of the bg color or flip the order of these two lines:

```
        nextViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        nextViewController.starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2"];
```

To this:

```
        nextViewController.starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2"];

        nextViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Then it works and the image displays correctly. Is this a bug? Or is this an issue with order of operations and views and how things are drawn on screen? Apologies if this isn't clear enough, I'm having a hard time putting to words what the exact issue is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is happening because when you access the view of StarViewController (with `nextViewController.view.backgroundColor`), this causes viewDidLoad to be executed. If the line to set the value of the image is after that line, then starImage will be nil when viewDidLoad runs.

Comment: Now that you say that, that sounds likely. I wasn't aware that accessing the view property would execute viewDidLoad.